# Angular Material Float Label Isn't floating

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material

I have an `angular form` on this `form` is two `angular material inputs`

There is an attribute from the doc which states you can make the label always float, so I tried to replicate it, but it didn't work for whatever reason.

Here is the HTML

```
<form *ngIf="frmNotes" [formGroup]="frmNotes">
                <mat-form-field [floatLabel]="always" style="width: 100%">
                    <input matInput placeholder="Subject" formControlName="subject" [(ngModel)]="note.subject">
                </mat-form-field>
                <mat-form-field [floatLabel]="always" style="width: 100%;">
                    <textarea formControlName="note" matInput placeholder="Write a note.." [(ngModel)]="note.value"></textarea>
                </mat-form-field>
            </form>
```

Here is the TS

```
import { Component } from "@angular/core";
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
import { ProfileService } from "../../services/profile-service";
import { FormGroup, FormBuilder, Validators } from "@angular/forms";

@Component({
    selector: 'note-component',
    templateUrl: 'note.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./note.component.css']
})

export class NoteComponent {
    notes: any;
    frmNotes: FormGroup;
    note: LooseObject = {};

    constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute, private profileService: ProfileService, private formBuilder: FormBuilder) {
      this.frmNotes = formBuilder.group({});
    }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.route.params.subscribe(res => {
            this.profileService.getNotes(res.id).subscribe(data => {
                this.notes = data.notes;
            }, err => console.error(err));

        });
        this.frmNotes = this.formBuilder.group({
            note: ['', Validators.required],
            subject: ['', Validators.required]
        });
    }

}
```

Here is an image of how it looks:
[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Square brackets indicates a template expression - `[floatLabel]="always"` will look for a variable named `always` in your component, essentially the equivalent of `floatLabel="{{always}}"`. You'll need to surround `always` in single quotes or remove the square brackets if you want to pass it directly: `[floatLabel]="'always'"` or `floatLabel="always"`.